# Trying to restore SMS messages after a factory reset

Tags: sms, backup, factory-reset, restore

Before I did a factory reset on my LG G3 I copied everything in the internal memory to my PC (drag and drop over USB) just in case I needed any of it later. What I stupidly forgot to do was make a backup of my text messages with an SMS backup app that I use. So I'm missing a lot of text messages that I really wanted to save (some with important information).

I have all the folders that were in the internal storage, so is there any way to just drag and drop back over certain folders to my current phone to access my old SMS messages? Or were they in a folder that wouldn't show up when connected to my PC and therefore didn't get backed up via drag and drop?

Comment: The latter. The message database cannot be directly accessed by a "normal user" (it belongs to the telephony provider, and is located in `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db` – a file you don't get to see via MTP.